# How do I add serial number by replacing character in string in Python?

Tags: python

oldName = "old_###"

now I want to convert all the "#" in to the serial number,
for example, in this case oldName should be "old_001"

is there any possible Pythonic Way to do this?

Comment: Do you know how many # you'll have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `###` isn't a requirement:

```
print 'old_{:03d}'.format(1)
```

If you need `###`, here's a way to compute the format string:

```
import re
name = "old_#####"
fmt = re.sub(r'#+',lambda m: r'{{:0{}d}}'.format(len(m.group(0))),name)
print name
print fmt
for i in range(5):
    print fmt.format(i)
```

#### Output

```
old_#####
old_{:05d}
old_00000
old_00001
old_00002
old_00003
old_00004
```

Comment: thanks for response, i'm getting error # Error: NameError: file line 1: name 'm' is not defined

Comment: Sorry, I must have edited after I tested the code and broke something.  Fixed.

Comment: awesome, this is what I want ! can i get this code in Python 2.X rather than Python 3, I should have mention this earlier.. Sorry !!

Answer (score 3):

Couldn't you just do:

```
oldName.replace('###', '001')
```

Of course my assumption here is that you always have 3 '#' symbols.

Simple is the best way to go I say, if this works you won't need to use the `re` module.

Answer (score 1):

Try it with string formatting:

```
number = 123
serial_number = "old_%03d" % number
```

Answer (score 1):

```
oldName = "old_{serial_number}"
oldName.format(serial_numer='001')
```

Of course, this assumes that you do not really have to use '#'.